# Possible to remove a dynamically created div in a grid display without its neighboring divs moving?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I have a parent div with

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
grid-template-rows: 50px;
```

then a javascript function creates 4 child divs that go into those columns.

is it possible to remove one of those child divs without the other divs sliding to the left to take its place?  Like some way to have the grid "hold" its walls in place whether or not there is a child div present?

Or do I have to create fixed child divs and then append those with the new divs instead?

Comment: don't remove it, make it invisible instead

Comment: Instead of removing the div, you could replace it with a "placeholder" div with the same dimensions but no content

Comment: I tried making it invisible instead and the neighboring divs still slid!  I do not understand how or why, but they did.  Replacing it with an empty placeholder seems like a decent option.  But might be cleaner to just create fixed child divs and append those instead..

Comment: Wait - no.  Making it invisible did work - I just had some other code wrong.. oops!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grid template pattern with named cells:

```
.thing {
    display: grid;
    // prettier-ignore
    grid-template:
      'cell_0_0 cell_1_0' 1fr
      'cell_0_1 cell_1_1' 1fr /
       1fr       1fr;
    grid-gap: 30px;
}

.item {
  grid-area: cell_0_1;
}
```

Then the grid will retain the grid areas just fine and keep your elements glued to the correct grid cell.

Answer (score 0):

For a specific child div, you want to keep all its properties except width and height. So `display: none;` won't work, commonly used to temporarily 'remove' specified HTML elements.

You must select the specified div, then `unset` its unwanted properties.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid coral;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  width : 70px;
  height : 250px;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

/* 'Hide' the second child div */
.child:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: unset;
  border: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

On the selected child div, you can also use `all: unset;` then set `width` and `height` again.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.  I'm just going to stick with visibility hidden for now, as it's working fine once I cleared up my other error !

Comment: Indeed `visibility: hidden;` does a much better job!